# Форматирование шрифта

Tags: css, шрифты, google-fonts, web-fonts

Использую шрифт [Baskervville](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Baskervville), а конкретнее его цифры.
Ввожу цифры от нуля до 9 и получается так, что одни цифры выше или ниже других. Можно ли как-то сделать так, что бы они были на одном уровне?
В фотошопе это работает изначально...

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baskervville&display=swap');

h1 {
  font-family: 'Baskervville';
}
```

```html
<h1>0123456789</h1>
```

Comment: можно попробовать выводить каждый символ в отдельном div а в контейнере указать text-align:center justify-content:center

Comment: Зачем? Это же фишка шрифта.

Comment: Впрочем попробуйте https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings `font-feature-settings: "onum" 0;`

Comment: Или `font-feature-settings: "tnum";`

Comment: @AlexeyTen, к сожалению, ничего из вышеперечисленного не помогло...

Comment: @santavital, тоже не помогло...

Comment: Впрочем не факт что шрифт в гугле содержит альтернативные глифы.